# Java Date mapping postgresql timestamp has no time, minutes and seconds

Tags: java, postgresql, date, timestamp, java.util.date

Java uses `java.util.Date` to save `timeStamp` type fields in postgresql database, and finds that there is no time, minutes and seconds, only year, month and day, which is very strange.

I have tried to convert it to `java.sql.Timestamp` at the Java level, and then save it to `timeStamp` in the database, and found that there is still no time.

I hope someone can help me solve this problem and why it caused such a result. I am very curious about this.

Comment: Recommendation that you stop using `java.util.Date`/`java.sql.Date`/`java.sql.TimeStamp` where possible and make use of the `java.time.*` class instead. See [Using Java 8 Date and Time classes](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/query/#using-java-8-date-and-time-classes) for more details

Comment: Also make sure the column is not `DATE` and is actually a variant of `TIMESTAMP` (as described in the link in my previous comment)

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your column?

Comment: It sounds weird. Are you using JDBC (`PreparedStatement`, for example)? A [mre], please?

Comment: Then I lost the test problem. The previous configuration with problems: the column field type of the database is timeStamp (postgresql), and java uses java.util.Date.

But I also think java.time.LocalDateTime should be used, which has been modified.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use either `Date` class, nor `Timestamp`.

Furthermore, apparently your database is storing a date-only. So both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are misfits. Those represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, not just a date.

## `DATE` column?

You neglected to tell us the data type of your column. But I would guess that the column is of [Postgres type `DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), given that you claim to be getting only year-month-day without any time-of-day.

The `DATE` type in Postgres is akin to the `DATE` type specified in the SQL standard.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

For a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `DATE`, the matching Java class mapped in [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2+ is `java.time.LocalDate`.

Write.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2023 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=myPreparedStatement.setObject https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself